# Master page and nested forms issue

Tags: asp.net

I have got master page with form (runat="server"). However in nested page, I have 2 forms. 
First is for changing password and second one is for submiting user data... 
Both must exist, with separate submit buttons.

I tried to enclose appropriate fields with form tags, but I got an error that enclosed forms are not allowed.... How can I achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET supports a single form per page only (it emulates desktop sessionful forms). Probably what you need is to leave the form in the master page and to have 2 Click handlers for the buttons on the content page. You may also need to specify ValidationGroup for your controls and buttons so that they don't interfere if you have some validators.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already form in master page, you will not be able to add any form in the nested page, there could be only one form tag per page,

rather than creating two different forms in nested page,
cant you create separate two different div, table etc

what force you to take form in nested page

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one < form > tag in ASPX page. When you are using Master page, it already has a  < form runat="server "> tag. You can not use < form > tag again in your nested pages. What you can do is add your content on nested page in this tag.
< asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server" >
< /asp:Content >

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple form on a webforms page, but only 1 can have the runat-"server' attribute and the runat="server" form cannot have any nested forms. One option that might work for you:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header>
        <h1>My Site</h1>
        <form id="SearchForm" action="search.aspx" method="post">
            <!--your search form html inputs (on server controls)-->
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- the standard webforms form used for server controls etc-->
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SearchBody" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You could also look at the PostBackUrl techinique:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `<form runat="server">` at the start of your master page after `<body>` tag and inside that put your `<asp:content></asp:content>`.

Ex. MyMasterPage.master page

```
<% master ... %>
<html>
<head> .... </head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
.
.
.
<div>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
</div>
.
.
.
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Nester Page : 
MyPage.cs

```
<% page ... %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Button ID="testButton" runat="server" Text="Sample Button" Width="135px" />
</asp:Content>
```

In this way you can solve your problem